# insert the javascript codes of another view returned from ajax to a view page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am doing an jquery ajax call in my rails application and in the controller I am rendering it to a view page(where javascripts codes are written). Then I need to insert the response returned from the server to a DOM element. When I try to alert the server response (alert (data))I am getting it completely. But when I insert it into the dom element($('#someid').html(data)) it is not inserting it completely as it contains lot of javascript codes. So can anyone please tell me how to insert the javascript codes of another view returned from ajax to a view page??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have got some issues with escaping characters.

This is a working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Y22QN/1/)

I'm using below code which works fine:

```
data = "<script>alert('test');<\/script><p>Dynamic Content with Script</p>"
$('#paste').html(data);​
```

However, it'll alert even without escaping script tag but will not render and execute it in DOM which I guess highlights your problem.